# on('click') jQuery does not work after 1st page in jQuery datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable, onclick

I have a datatable with records. As part of the records there is a dynamic delete button to delete the selected record. The ID of the selected record is stored in a span which is hidden.

When the delete button is selected on the 1st page of the datatable it is firing the onClick fine. The problem is if  I go to any page after the 1st page on the datatable (for example page 2) and click the delete button, it does not do anything, it just refreshes the page. Note that this only happens after the 1st page within the datatable.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSchedule" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="table table-sm table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" ClientIDMode="Static" DataKeyNames="ScheduleID" OnRowCommand="gvSchedule_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CenterName" HeaderText="CenterName" SortExpression="CenterName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EPType" HeaderText="Software" SortExpression="EPType" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="Resource" SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}" SortExpression="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StartTime" HeaderText="StartTime" SortExpression="StartTime" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EndTime" HeaderText="EndTime" SortExpression="EndTime" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventDescription" HeaderText="Event" SortExpression="EventDescription" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="InstallMethod" HeaderText="Install Method" SortExpression="InstallMethod" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="InstallationComplete" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="InstallationComplete" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span id="ScheduleID" style="display: none"><%# Eval("ScheduleID") %></span>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnViewSchedule" ImageUrl="~/assets/images/edit.png" Style="width: 20px; height: 18px;" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ScheduleID") + ";" +Eval("CenterID")%>' CommandName="selectrow" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" ImageUrl="~/assets/images/delete.png" Style="width: 20px; height: 18px;" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id*=btnDelete]').on("click", function () {
    var ScheduleID = $(this).closest('tr').find('span').text();

        if (confirm("Are you sure you would like to delete the selected schedule?")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ScheduleOverview.aspx/DeleteSchedule",
                data: "{'ScheduleID': '" + ScheduleID + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    swal("Information", "Schedule Successfully Deleted", "success");
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```

Please assist me how I can make the delete button work after the 1st page of the jQuery datatable. Thank you.

Comment: As a side note: `id` attributes should be unique per document. Unless you absolutely can't change the markup, you should be using `class`.

Comment: The id is unique. Is it better practice to use classes?

Comment: Oh, is there some asp magic that replaces the `ID` in `<asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete"` with something unique? I've never touched ASP, so ... if it does, never mind ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is being dynamically replaced, which the handler on `document.ready` can't pick up. You will need to use the [delegating variant of `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) instead:

```
$('body').on('click', '[id*=btnDelete]', function() { ...
```

Side note: as @Wanton aptly mentioned it is preferable to not bind event handlers to 'body' if avoidable. If there is a wrapper element that will not be dynamically replaced, you should use it to bind the event to instead.

Comment: Binding event handler to `body` is bad. You should keep scope of event delegation small as possible. Now if OP adds anything else to page that has elements with ids containing "btnDelete",  that event handler will be triggered.

Comment: @vzwick maybe add a warning then?

Comment: @vzwick warning because people have tendency to copy&paste stuff from here.

Comment: @Wanton I agree with you but when I name my ids they are always different so in this case there will never be a button or any control with the name "btnDelete"

Comment: @LyubomirIvanovValchev because you use `[id*=btnDelete]` that asterisk makes it to match `btnDelete` inside id, so it will match `btnDeleteOtherThing` too. Also if you remove your grid from DOM with jQuery that event handler still stays bound to `body`.

Comment: Ok I fully understand now, I didn't know this about the asterisk...So thanks for mentioning it

Answer (score 1):

`$('[id*=btnDelete]')` finds all elements currently in page and bounds click to them. So after you change page those new btnDelete buttons don't have click event attached to them.
Wrap your grid with div and give it an id like "gvScheduleWrapper" and do event binding like this to use event delegation.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#gvScheduleWrapper").on("click", "[id*=btnDelete]", function () {
      // You delete handling code here 
    });
});`
```

Comment: Thank you. I will keep this in mind as a second variant

Comment: @LyubomirIvanovValchev You shouldn't do it as vzwick suggest, don't bind events like this to `body`.

Comment: I tried your answer and it is working fine. What I also tried is this:  $("#gvSchedule").on("click", "[id*=btnDelete]", function () and it is working fine.I basically call the table id and it works exactly the same way as creating a div and wrapping the grid around the div (what you said above). So keeping this in mind is there a need to create a div and wrap the whole table around the div? If so, why?

Comment: @LyubomirIvanovValchev - there is no *need* to create a wrapper div per se, but you'll be relying on the GridView component to exhibit consistent behavior (i.e. not to delete and reinsert/replace itself dynamically) through any and all updates yet to come. The wrapper is a safer variant.

Comment: @LyubomirIvanovValchev  It's been long time since I've used Webforms and one thing I remember those id's are not real client id's, instead they are generated by Webforms. That `asp:GridView` probably creates div with some id, if you can bind your event handler there that might work as well. Risk is that it uses some `UpdatePanel` crap and you'll lose that bound event just like before.

Comment: Thank you both for the clarification @vzwick

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this also for effective way.

```
$("#gvSchedule").on('click', '[id*=btnDelete]', function() {
    //here goes your code
});
```